# Connecting dots without crossing lines

Tags: javascript, graph

I am trying to create a Javascript web application where a user clicks on a canvas to drop an infinite amount of dots. There is solve button, that when clicked draws lines between the dots so that all dots are connected by exactly 2 other dots, and no lines can cross. With my code so far, there are certain instances where the lines still cross, and I can't programmatically figure out logic that will connect all the dots without any lines ever crossing.

So far, I collect all the points (X-Y coordinates) and put them in a JavaScript array of objects. I then need to sort the array so that it is in the correct order to be drawn. Everything works at this point except the order does not always satisfy the requirements.

My Question: Does anyone have any ideas on a set of rules that will order these points (X-Y coordinates) so that they all connect but never cross, that will work in every scenario?

Thanks for your help.

```
    var centroid = get_polygon_centroid($points);

    $points = _.sortBy($points, function(p){
        var dx = p.coords.x-centroid.x;
        var dy = p.coords.y-centroid.y;
        return dx*dx + dy*dy;
    });

    $points = _.sortBy($points, function(p){
        var dx = p.coords.x-centroid.x;
        var dy = p.coords.y-centroid.y;
        return Math.atan2(dy, dx);
    });

    $points.push($points[0]);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an algorithm:

- Find the center of mass ( O(n) time, where n is the number of points)
- For each point, compute the angle from the center to that point ( O(n) time). This can be done with `Math.atan2(p.y-c.y, p.x-c.x)` in JS where p is the current point and c is the center.
- Sort by angle ( O(n log n) time). For any angles that are *exactly* the same, sort by radius next, smallest to largest.
- Connect pairs of points a<sub>i</sub> to a<sub>i+1</sub> for every i from 0 to n-1 and also a<sub>n-1</sub> to a<sub>0</sub>

This should result in a connected graph where no two lines intersect in O(n log n) time.

---

**Update**:

This code should work.

```
//iterate through all points and calculate the center, c
var c = {x:0, y:0}, p;
for (p : points) {
    c.x+=p.coords.x;
    c.y+=p.coords.y;
}

c.x/=points.length;
c.y/=points.length;


points.sort(function(p1, p2){
    var dx1 = p1.coords.x-c.x;
    var dy1 = p1.coords.y-c.y;
    var a1 = Math.atan2(dy1, dx1);

    var dx2 = p2.coords.x-c.x;
    var dy2 = p2.coords.y-c.y;
    var a2 = Math.atan2(dy2, dx2);

    //If angles are the same, sort by length
    if (a1===a2){
        var d1 = dx1*dx1 + dy1*dy1;
        var d2 = dx2*dx2 + dy2*dy2;

        return d1-d2;
    }

    //otherwise sort by angle
    return a1-a2;
}

//Iterate through all Points and draw lines between them
var i;
for (i=0;i<n;i++){
    //This is not real code \/
    line(p[i], p[(i+1)%n]);
}
```

Comment: Is that this algorithm? can you mark the center of mass you found? I did a mental proof of correctness yesterday, and it should be correct, but the screenshot you posted doesn't look it followed my algorithm.

Comment: Updated the code to match yours. Everything should be working now. I think you were having issues calculating the centroid. I kept getting NaN using your function.

Comment: You should give me some credit on your site, since I not only came up with a much faster algorithm, but also wrote most of the code for you :P

Comment: Jason, I have been asked to remove this question because it is used in the hiring process at a company, and the staff would rather the answer to this tricky question not be available online. Would you mind removing your answer so that I may delete the question? It would be much appreciated.